# JEST testcase should failed with try-catch

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, try-catch, enzyme, testcase

I am wondering why my below test case is passing after using the try-catch block, While it should fail:

```
test("test", () => {
  try {
    expect(true).toBe(false);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

While without try-catch it is failing:

```
test("test", () => {
  expect(true).toBe(false);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A test will only fail if an error is thrown.

The assertion, `expect(true).toBe(false);`, will throw an error, which Jest will catch and record the test as failed.

However, using a try-catch block will catch the error and allow you to handle it as you wish.

In your case, you are just console logging it so there is no longer an error for Jest to catch... so the test passes.

If you were to re-throw the error in your `catch` block, then Jest will catch it and fail the test:

```
test("test", () => {
  try {
    expect(true).toBe(false);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err; // <— Re-throw error
  }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Working perfectly, Thanks!